# The JavaScript engine optimizes hot loops, but what about while(true)?

Tags: javascript, optimization, v8

According to the YDKJSY book, if we use while(true), we will get an infinity loop until the browser crashes. In contrast, when I read about the JavaScript engine that optimizes hot loops or functions, I was confused. Here is an example from the https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/prototypes. In Javascript engine, a lot of things are done to optimize for-loops, and on the other hand, while(true){} does nothing until the browser crashes. What's the point?

> Let’s take a look at a concrete example and see how the pipelines in
> the different engines deal with it. Here’s some code that gets
> repeated often, in a hot loop.

```
let result = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 4242424242; ++i) {
    result += i;
}
console.log(result);
```

> V8 starts running the bytecode in the Ignition interpreter. At some
> point the engine determines that the code is hot and starts up the
> TurboFan frontend, which is the part of TurboFan that deals with
> integrating profiling data and constructing a basic machine
> representation of the code. This is then sent to the TurboFan
> optimizer on a different thread for further improvements.

Here are some codes to consider:

```
while(true){}
console.log("Hi there!");
```

---

```
while(true){
console.log("Hi there!");
}
```

Comment: I guess it's hard to optimise infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what kind of loop you're using. Consider:

```
let i = 0;
while (true) {
  if (i > 4242424242) break;
  i++;
}
```

While that's technically a `while (true)`-loop, it doesn't run forever, and could well contain useful code. V8 doesn't care whether you write your loop like this, or in classic `for` loop syntax.

Also, `while (true) {}` is not the only way to write a useless empty infinite loop, you can also do that using e.g. `for (let i = 0; i >= 0; i++) {}` or just `for (;;);`.

In short:

- JavaScript engines optimize hot code.
- Long running loops count as "hot".
- Whether it's a `for` or a `while` loop doesn't matter.
- Whether it runs long or infinitely long doesn't matter. (For non-trivial examples, this is [impossible to predict up front](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), and for trivial examples such as an empty infinite loop it doesn't really matter what the engine does, so it might as well always do the same thing: execute the loop you give it, leaving it up to you to decide whether that's a useful loop to execute.)